# Is it possible to mark a tweet field in_reply_to_status_id pointing to a RT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-gem

I am using Twitter Ruby Wrapper API for Rails( https://github.com/sferik/twitter ), when I do like:

client.update("Replying a Retweet", :in_reply_to_status_id => twitter_being_replied_id)

It returns a Tweet with a null in_reply_to_status_id field.

Replying a normal Tweet works fine.

So I'm wondering if the problem is replying a retweet or the gem.

Answer (score 2):

Replying to a Retweet using `in_reply_to_status_id` should work as expected with the Ruby wrapper. However, please make sure you include the @username of the user who retweeted the Tweet in the text of the reply for this parameter to work.

Here is a note extracted from the documentation of [statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update):

> Note: This parameter will be ignored unless the author of the tweet
>   this parameter references is mentioned within the status text.
>   Therefore, you must include @username, where username is the author of
>   the referenced tweet, within the update.

Comment: Twitter also used to require that the @username be the first thing in the tweet. They may have relaxed that requirement, but if you are still having problems, I'd try that.

Comment: I just tested. It worked if I mention the -@username- of the Original Tweet, but it did not work if I mention just the -@username- who posted the RT. Could someone please confirm this? In this case my Tweet points to the original Tweet, even if I pass the RT Id.